# Arrange multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql

I have this code right here:

```
SELECT t1.location AS LOCATION,
  (CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2815' THEN t2.value END) Reading,
  (CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2620' THEN t2.value END) Flw,
  (CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2618' THEN t2.value END) Prs,
  (CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2595' THEN t2.value END) Lvl

FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.locid

WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                FROM table2 t2 
                WHERE t1.id = t2.locid)

GROUP BY t1.location
```

This code already gets the latest values. I only need it to arrange it in one single row. How can I do that?

The output that I want is like this:

```
LOCATION  | READING  | FLW | PRS  | LVL
east/flw  | 13.7     | 8.5 | 35.6 | 40.5
```

Here is the sample data, I thought it would just be easier to link it here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b05c9/1

Comment: I was just about to write an answer that makes one huge single line of your SQL statement, when I realized that is not what you want...

Comment: You have four different values in location. Do you want them to Group BY in a same group?

Comment: Please delete your question from here or [dba.se].

Comment: @Santhosh right now i don't mind what's going to show on the location even if its flw, reading etc. my worries right now is i want it to show in one single row.

Comment: Then, I suppose you are only interested in the other columns and not location.

Comment: @Santhosh right now, yes. i really need it to be arranged in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'east/flw' AS LOCATION, 
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2815' THEN t2.value ELSE 0 END), 2) AS Reading,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2620' THEN t2.value ELSE 0  END), 2) AS Flw,
  ROUND(sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2618' THEN t2.value ELSE 0  END), 2) AS Prs,
 ROUND( sum(CASE WHEN t2.locid = '2595' THEN t2.value ELSE 0  END), 2) AS Lvl

FROM table2 t2

INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.locid

WHERE t2.t_stamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.t_stamp) 
                    FROM table2 t2 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.locid)



GROUP BY 'east/flw'
```

Comment: from your code, what if i want to check out the values for like 1 hour ago, how can i do that part? Do i just add `DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 HOUR` on the where clause?

Comment: To do that, you do something like follows in WHERE clause. I am not sure of the function or syntax, but it roughly follows this idea: HOUR(NOW() - DATE_COL) = 1

Comment: btw, just wanted to ask, why did you use sum?

Comment: do i remove the current query that's in the where clause and then just add the code for the time interval?

Comment: @hearmeroar SUM is an aggregate function, that rolls up data based on GROUP BY columns. And Yes, it is up to you whether you hard code or otherwise in your WHERE clause

Comment: I have a problem wondering if you could help me out on the time interval part, can you check this out? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c2c/5
i changed the time on the 2nd value of loc id - 2815 and i think it got the sum of both values. 

And then next what i did was i changed the minute on the 2nd value of loc id and then result it showed was the 1st value, it should've shown the 2nd value. how can i fix this?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf44/6

Comment: i guess if both values have the same hour and minute, maybe get the latest value based on the seconds?

Comment: You are selecting only Max timestamp for a locid. That's why you get the first record for 2815. You need to look here. You change the minute part of second record of 2815 to 40 and run the query. Now, you'll get the values for that record. you need to look this in WHERE condition and see whether you are using for what do you need

Comment: I think i need something that will check the date and time. something like if that id have the same date, check the time, and if the time is the same, like if the hour and minutes is the same, then check the seconds to get the older value, so the lower the number of the seconds is, thats the older value. is that right?